# In in-universe time, how long did the "first" part of the movie last?

Tags: your-name

Vague title, I realize, but I don't want to spoil any passersby. Here's my question, spoilered to keep people browsing /questions from seeing it:

> How long was it from the first time that Taki and Mitsuha swapped until the last time (the day before the comet struck)? Relatedly, how long was it from when they *realized* they were swapping until the last time they swapped?

The sense I got is that it had to be a fairly long time (some number of months, perhaps), based on details like how they had pinned down that the swaps occur 2-3 times a week, and how each of them had gotten quite good at fitting into the other's life.

However, during the first scene that is set in Mitsuha's present with her in her own body, the TV news indicates that the comet is due to approach perigee within a month, and at this point, they hadn't yet figured out that they were swapping, which suggests to me that at best they could've had a few weeks where they were aware of the swapping phenomenon. (Granted, the swapping could've been going on for considerably longer with both of them still believing the swaps to just be vivid dreams.)

So the timelines seem a bit wonky to me. Can we pin down the duration of the "first" part of the movie more accurately?

I suspect that we should be able to get relatively tight bounds at least on how long they were aware of the swapping by examining the details of the diary entries Mitsuha was keeping on Taki's phone. (Or maybe this info could be found in the novelization?)

Answer (score 1):

It's never stated. However, judging by the amount of different coloured diary logs in Taki's phone, it's likely to be that they switched for at least 2 months. The section where Zen Zen Zense plays can't be used as reference as it is unlcear as to when each event happened.

In terms, I'd say that they took a week of switches to realise the changes, and took another month getting completely used to it. Add a month after that, and that should fufill the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki to the movie has a full timeline with as many dates and times as people could find: https://kiminonawa.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline#Story

According to it, the first switch was on the 3rd of September 2013/2016, the last regular one on the 2nd of October 2013/2016 (so exactly one month) and the very last one on the 4th of October 2013 and the 22nd of October 2016.